# What is the relationship between ramification in central simple algebras and in fields?

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, ramification, central-simple-algebras, global-fields

Suppose $K$ is the field of fractions of a Dedekind domain $R$, and let $L$ be a finite extension of $K$. There is a notion of ramification of primes of $K$ in $L$, which describes how $\mathfrak p \subset R$ decomposes into prime ideals in the ring of integers of $L$.

There is also a notion of ramification of central simple algebras over $K$: if $D/K$ is a central simple algebra, it is said to be split if $D_{\mathfrak p} := D \otimes_K K_{\mathfrak p} \cong M_{n}(K_{\mathfrak p})$, and otherwise it is said to be ramified. It is said to be totally ramified if $D_{\mathfrak p}$ is a skew-field.

These seem like very different notions, but the terminology suggests otherwise.

**Question 1:** Are these two notions related, and if so, how?

In particular, I would like to understand the logic behind the following claim which I have encountered:

> For $L$ and $K$ as above, fix a central simple algebra $D$ over $L$.
> Then $D$ is also a (non-central) simple algebra over $K$. For
> $\mathfrak p \subset R$, if $D_{\mathfrak p}$ is a skew-field, then
> $\mathfrak p$ is totally ramified in $L$.

In the situation I am considering, $\mathfrak p$ is a non-archimedean prime, so if necessary one can assume this. Does it have something to do with valuations on $D$ extending the valuation corresponding to $\mathfrak p$?

**Question 2:** Assuming the answer to question 1 is affirmative, is there a way to see inertia on the central simple algebra side?

Comment: Ramification in central simple algebras is closely connected to both ramification and residue field extension in fields. For example, if a central simple algebra is totally ramified at a prime $p$, then all its subfields will be either ramified or have nontrivial residue field extension at $p$ (i.e. $p$ won't split). I think they just picked one to name it after.

Comment: @Will Sawin: Could you give me the arguments for those statements or direct me to a source?

Comment: That has a simple proof: By definition, the algebra is totally ramified at $p$ if and only if the tensor product with $\mathbb Q_p$ is a skew field. If the algebra contains a field $K$ where $p$ splits, then its tensor product with $\mathbb Q_p$ contains $K \otimes \mathbb Q_p$, which is a product of two fields and thus contains zero divisors. But it's not possible for a skew field to contain zero divisors.